# iterator between jumped id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a SQL table with the following example data;

```
 id     | postTitle | postTitle
------- | --------- | ----------
  1     | some text | some text
------- | --------- | ----------
  5     | some text | some text
------- | --------- | ----------
  10    | some text | some text
```

And Also I have two buttons to get next or prev post: Prev and Next.
Is it possible to create an iterator which passing from id=5 to id=10 by just one clicking on Next button.
Thanks!

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID > 5 ORDER BY ID

Comment: Thanks, but, the 5 is not constant number. Normally id is increment. but after deleting rows I faced with this problem.

Comment: Of course, this an offset solution. you are browsing post X and the user clicks in next you just query `SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID > X ORDER BY ID` you get 10, browse 10, and so on.

Comment: create some UDF which will work as @kblok suggest... and just pass current `id`  to this function

Comment: What kind of iterator?   Why can't you just use a foreach loop over your DataTable?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: The delta between 1 to 5 is 4, while the delta between 5 to 10 is 5.  So the Ids should be either 0,5,10 OR 1,6,11 to give even spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution With SQL Query!
Thanks for everyone.

Here is the solution below:

**For the PREVbutton :**

select * from tblPosts where postID=(select max(postID) from tblPosts where postID< @id)

**For the NEXT button :**

select * from tblPosts where postID=(select min(postID) from tblPosts where postID> @id)